# positioning of images relatively to each other and page with \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

In the below code i tried to get the bottle at the same height as of the cardbox so that the right side of the bottle image is at the right side of the page. I tried to do something like :

```
  \node at (0,\textwidth) (bottle)  [anchor=north east]
    {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{bottle_water}};
```

but this does not place the image at the right height.

The result of what i want in libreoffice is here:
[image]

```
\begin{document}
  \begin{center} \huge
  english - french \\
  \end{center}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0,0) (cardbox) [inner sep=0pt]
    {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{cardboard}};
  \draw[anchor=north west, text width=3cm, inner sep=0.3cm,outer sep=0.3cm]
    (cardbox.east) node[draw] (this) {This is a box \\ Ceci est une boîte}
    (cardbox.south west) node[draw] (that) {That's a bottle \\ Celà est une bouteille};
  \node at (cardbox.east) (bottle)  [anchor=north east]
    {\includegraphics[height=4cm]{bottle_water}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image: bottle]
[image: cardbox]

Comment: Not related but `cela` doesn't take an accute accent ;)

Comment: yes, true. I got confused with another word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
  \begin{center} \huge
  english - french \\
  \end{center}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
   lbl/.style = {draw,text width=34mm}
                        ]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
\path   (0,0) node (cardbox) [box, right] {\includegraphics{albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (botle) [box, left] {\includegraphics{A2eDdiT}};
\node[lbl, right=of cardbox]  {This is a box \\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node[lbl, left =of botle]    {That's a bottle \\ Celà est une bouteille};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (1):**
Your question as well comment (unfortunately) is not very clear to me. Now I guess that you like to have the following:

[image]

If this is not what you after, please provide a sketch how the nodes with images and boxes should be positioned in your images

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
  \begin{center} \huge
  english - french \\
  \end{center}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 5mm and 22 mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
   lbl/.style = {draw,text width=34mm}
                        ]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
\path   (0,0) node (cardbox) [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (botle) [box, left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
%
\node (lbl-1) [lbl, above right=of cardbox.east]  {This is a box \\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (lbl-2) [lbl, below right=of cardbox.east]    {That's a bottle \\ Celà est une bouteille};
%
\node[left =2mm of lbl-1,font=\huge] {\rightpointleft};
\node[right=2mm of lbl-2,font=\huge] {\leftpointright};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2):**
This suggestion is very opinion based. I would use `callout` shapes and directed pointers relative to node with note. Les fancy but clear and with simpler code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shapes.callouts
                }
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 13 mm,
   box/.style = {inner sep=0pt},
  note/.style = {rectangle callout, callout relative pointer={(#1)},
                 callout pointer width=4mm, 
                 draw, ultra thick, rounded corners,
                 text width=41mm, inner sep=3mm, font=\large}
                    ]
\setkeys{Gin}{height=4cm}
\path   (0,0)           node (cardbox)  [box, right] {\includegraphics{jpg/albIe7h}}
        (\linewidth,0)  node (botle)    [box,  left] {\includegraphics{jpg/A2eDdiT}};
\node (n1) [note={-9mm,1mm},
            right=of cardbox.east]
           {This is a box\\ Ceci est une boîte};
\node (n2) [note={17mm,2mm},
            below=of n1]
           {That's a bottle\\ Celà est une bouteille};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: here the graphics: https://imgur.com/xNiad3b  ; https://imgur.com/PvKfYm2

Comment: really nice. Actually i didn't mention it, but the two text boxes have to be close to the cardbox exactly as the box saying "This is a box ..." and the other just vertically aligned to it and underneath, with maybe 1cm space. I have two vector graphics of a hand which i would like to attach to the boxes (posted in the comments). Here is an image of how it should look like: i.stack.imgur.com/tY7XB.png

Comment: @user1850133, see addendum. Do I guess right what you after?

Comment: can you add comments, especially for (lbl-1) and (lbl-2). I'm trying to get the text boxes as close as possible to the cardbox. And move the left hand to the top of the corresponding textbox. Also i've seen on the web that dingbat also has a hand version that seems to point to something close. The two hands really have to reflect the distance at which they are pointing. The right hand could even be replaced by a forearm or a full arm with pointing finger.

Comment: here is what i did in libreoffice

Comment: @user1850133, with wee bit effort you can do  all desired changes yourself :-).  Just experiment with codes which you now have available. By experimenting and reading some introductory text about Ti*k*Z (for example https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en: Minimal introduction to TikZ (unofficial) , Part TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogrammwill from TikZ & PGF manual) make you more familiar with it. `(lbl-1)` and `(lbl-2)` are names of nodes with your text. BTW, you not provide what you do by libreoffice.

Comment: it seems there was a problem with the link. I updated the post.

Comment: Since you used things like above, right of ... to place the box i really don´t see how to tune thing for somewhat custom positions. I was already reading the doc, but the style is not proper for people used in reading scientific style documents. Did you check the image of what i did with libroffice?

Comment: could you change the way your code is for positioning the first and and second images so that just repeating this code with different images and text will make lualatex automatically appending or creating a new page? Right now the "at (0,0)" and "(\linewidth,0)" make it impossible.

Comment: Deare @user1850133, please ask new question where provide an example of small nut complete document (MWE: Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your problem and which we can anyone test and see what is going wrong. So far I don't see why any of the proposed solutions don't work properly. BTW, try your self replaced this two coordinates with some others, for example `(1,0)` and (12,0)` or ˙with any other for which you estimate to be more appropriate.

Comment: i have dozens of image pairs like this to append in the document. the "\path   (0,0)  " will not work for the subsequent images. I tried something like "\node (anothercardbox) [box, anchor=north west, below=18mm of cardbox] {\includegraphics{...}}" but it should place it automatically as per the height of the textboxes. Also for the second image of the pair "(\linewidth,0)  node (anotherbottle)..." the "0" in the coordinates needs to be manually updated.